# DotNetNuke module error - Sorry, an error occured on the page

Tags: asp.net, dotnetnuke

I get error with this URL - `www.example.com/error.html?aspxerrorpath=/Default.aspx` and this description `"Sorry, an error occurred on the page. We apologise for the inconvenience."` - when I click on Edit Content in Module Menu. Yesterday, however, it entered edit content section, but the same error popped up when I clicked Update.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

The problem was something about DotNetNuke configuration.

This is also a solution to error - "potentially dangerous request.form value was detected from the client"

All you need to do is edit `web.config` and add this attribute in `httpRuntime` tag - `requestValidationMode="2.0"`

Restart the application through IIS and it should work now.